# what is the difference between Strong Fréchet derivative and Fréchet derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

I am confused about the relationship between Frechet differentiable and strong Fréchet differentiable.

Assume the function $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}, x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is Fréchet differentiable at $x$.

Then we have $$\lim_{x \neq y^1 \to x} \frac{f(y^1) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y^1-x)}{\Vert y^1-x\Vert} = 0$$

$$\lim_{x \neq y^2 \to x} \frac{f(y^2) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y^2-x)}{\Vert y^2-x\Vert} = 0$$

Then use the first equation minus the second one and the inequality $\Vert y^1-x\Vert \leq \Vert y^1-y^2\Vert + \Vert y^2 - x\Vert$, then we get

$$\lim_{\substack{y^1 \neq y^2 \\ (y^1, y^2) \to (x, x)}} \frac{f(y^1) - f(y^2) - \nabla f(x)^T(y^1-y^2)}{\Vert y^1 - y^2 \Vert} = 0, $$
which is the definition of strong F-derivative.

---

It seems I did not use any other condition but F-derivative to get strong F-derivative. I am quite confused about their difference.

Comment: You cannot add the equations and use the inequality for the denominator: it only works for non-negative numerator. If you take absolute value in the limit equation, then adding them does not help. So, strong is strictly strong than non-strong.

Comment: But I found they use similar argument in this paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689880, pp 297. to prove the upper bound for the difference of denominator.

Comment: @one user I believe the difference between that argument and yours boils down to the hypotheses in part (a) of Proposition $2.7$ that "*If* $\ D_xF(x_0,y_0)\ $ *is strong*," and in part that (b) "*If both* $\ D_xF(x_0,y_0)\ $ *and* $\ D_yF(x_0,y_0)\ $ *are strong*" *then* the conclusions follow.  Those hypotheses are essential for the proofs of those conclusions to work.  You have no similar hypotheses in your argument,

Comment: @lonzaleggiera the function $f$ has only one argument.

Comment: I have reproduced the text quoted from the paper you cited as using a "similar argument" to yours exactly as it's written in that paper. The argument of the function $\ F\ $ in that paper is split into two parts for notational convenience because it lies in a cross product $\ X\times Y\ $ of two normed linear spaces $\ X\ $ and $\ Y\ $, and the author wants to vary each part of the argument separately while keeping the other fixed.

Comment: The argument of *your* function $\ f\ $ lies in $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $, so its "one" argument has $\ n\ $ separate variables unless $\ n=1\ $.  Except in the latter case, you could just as easily split the argument of $\ f\ $ into two parts $\ x_1\in\mathbb{R}^p\ $ and $\ x_2\in\mathbb{R}^q\ $ with $\ p+q=n\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thanks for your reply. Actually, I do not understand why the argument in the paper is different from mine. As you can see in the paper, they use partial strong derivative twice for the difference, while the first part is bounded by $o(\Vert h_1\Vert)$ and the second part is bounded by  $o(\Vert h_2\Vert)$. Then they say the difference of these two parts is bounded by $o(\Vert h_1-h_2\Vert)$.

Comment: Then I just use the similar argument. Just use definition of F-derivative twice. The first part is bounded by $o(\Vert y^1-x\Vert)$ and the second part is bounded by $o(\Vert y^2-x\Vert)$. Then I say the difference is bounded by $o(\Vert y^1-y^2\Vert)$, which is just the definition of strong F-derivative.

Comment: But something bounded by $\ \ o\big(\left\|y_1-x\right\|\big)\ $ plus something bounded by $\ \ o\big(\left\|y_2-x\right\|\big)\ $ can be as large as $\ o\big(\left\|y_1-x\right\|\big)+o\big(\left\|y_2-x\right\|\big)\ $, and this is *not* necessarily bounded by $\ o\big(\left\|y_1-y_2\right\|\big)\ $.

Comment: Suppose the first bound is $\ \left\|y_1-x\right\|^2\ $, for instance, which is certainly $\ o\big(\left\|y_1-x\right\|\big)\ $, and the second bound is $\ \left\|y_2-x\right\|^2\ $, again certainly  $\ o\big(\left\|y_2-x\right\|\big)\ $.

Comment: But if   $\ y_1=x+\epsilon\ u $, $\ y_2=x+\big(\epsilon+\epsilon^4\big)u\ $, where $\ \|u\|=1\ $, then $\ \frac{\left\|y_1-x\right\|^2+\left\|y_2-x\right\|^2}{\|y_1-y_2\|}=\frac{2\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^5+\epsilon^8}{\epsilon^4}=\frac{2+2\epsilon^3+\epsilon^6}{\epsilon^2}\ $ does *not* tend to $\ 0\ $ as $\ \epsilon\rightarrow0\ $, so $\ \left\|y_1-x\right\|^2+\left\|y_2-x\right\|^2\ $is most definitely *not* $\ o\big(\left\|y_1-y_2\right\|\big)\ $.

Answer (score 1):

The typical counterexample is $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = 0, \\ x^2 \sin(x^{-1}) & \text{if } x \ne 0. \end{cases}$$
This function is Fréchet differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$, but not strictly/strongly Fréchet differentiable at $x = 0$.

Since $f'(0) = 0$, it is also very instructive (and not too hard) to use this counterexample and see where your argument fails.

If I remember correctly, one even has the following: If the function $f$ is Fréchet differentiable everywhere, then the strict/strong differentiability is equivalent to the continuity of the derivative.